# Why do Excel and Matlab give different results?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have 352k values and I want to find the most frequent values from all of them.
Numbers are rounded to two decimal places.
I use the commands `mode(a)` in Matlab and `mode(B1:B352000)` in Excel, but the results are different.

Where did I make a mistake, or which one can I believe?

Thanks

//edit: When I use other commands like `average`, the results are the same.

Comment: I think you should rephrase the title of your question. This has nothing to do with accuracy. Ask about the algorithms implemented by MATLAB and Excel for computing the mode, and why they would produce a different answer.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. So try to provide example data for which the problem can be generated.

Comment: Provide the data and it should be easy to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)):

> For a sample from a continuous distribution, such as [0.935..., 1.211..., 2.430..., 3.668..., 3.874...], the concept is unusable in its raw form, since no two values will be exactly the same, so each value will occur precisely once. In order to estimate the mode of the underlying distribution, the usual practice is to discretize the data by assigning frequency values to intervals of equal distance, as for making a histogram, effectively replacing the values by the midpoints of the intervals they are assigned to. The mode is then the value where the histogram reaches its peak. For small or middle-sized samples the outcome of this procedure is sensitive to the choice of interval width if chosen too narrow or too wide

Thus, it is likely that the two programs use a different interval size, yielding different answers. You can believe both (I presume) but knowing that the value returned is an approximation to the true mode of the undelying distribution.