# Efficient way to get the value that is the most duplicated in a Matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the value that is the most duplicated (and the percentage of times that it is duplicated). Here is an example:

```
A = [5 5 1 2 3 4 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 8];
```

`mostduplicatevalue(A)` should return 8 and the percentage is 4/length(A).

I am currently doing the following (see below), but it takes approx 5/6 seconds to obtain the result for a matrix of 1300*5000. What is a better way to achieve this result?

```
function [MostDuplicateValue, MostDuplicatePerc] = mostduplicatevalue(A)
% What is the value that is duplicates the most and what percentage of the
% sample does it represent?

% Value that is Most Duplicated
tbl     = tabulate(A(:));
[~,bi]  = max(tbl(:,2));

MostDuplicateValue = tbl(bi,1);
MostDuplicatePerc  = tbl(bi,3)/100;

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible answer:

```
function [MostDuplValue, MostDuplPerc, MostDuplCount] = mostduplicatevalue(A)
% What is the value that is duplicates the most and what percentage of the
% sample does it represent?

[MostDuplValue,MostDuplCount] = mode(A(:));
MostDuplPerc = MostDuplCount / sum(sum(~isnan(A)));

end
```

Comment: Mode computation requires the building of a histogram, which often is approximate. Different software will compute different modes. Your example is with small integers, this will likely be correct. With [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) you can control the creation of the histogram.

Comment: Hmm interesting point, because in my real example I am actually having a lot of numbers with many decimals after the comma. Do you expect it to fail?

Comment: it *could* give the wrong answer. For example: imagine you have 100 times 1.01, 60 times 2.63, and 60 times 2.64. There are another values, such that the histogram function bins 2.63 and 2.64 together. That bin will have 120 elements, be the largest bin, and you'll get 2.63 (for example) as output, instead of 1.01. I actually don't know how `mode` goes back to actual values, it might inspect all values that fall within the bin and pick one of them, or their means, or it might return the bin center. It's approximate by definition.

Comment: `unique` could be a way to approach this, depending on how many unique values you actually have. On the other hand, with floating-point values, approximate equality is more meaningful. So maybe binning 2.63 and 2.64 together is the correct thing to do?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Mode computation doesn't require building a histogram. In fact, Matlab's `mode` doesn't do that. It sorts the input, computes run lengths, and picks the element with the longest run

Comment: @LuisMendo: I wasn't aware that this is how MATLAB computes the mode. "Requires" was probably too strong a word. But a histogram is the usual way of computing the mode. For example, with real experimental data, no two samples are identical, you need a histogram to compute the mode of the underlying distribution. It all depends on how you define "mode". See here for a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134025/7328782

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, equality between floating-point values is always tricky

Answer (score 3):

Solution based on first sorting the array (very costly operation) and then finding the longest streak of the same number with `diff`. Empirically it seems to be slightly faster (takes about 2/3 of the duration of your proposal at 1300x5000). Has the side benefit that if multiple numbers occur the most, it will return all of them.

```
% sort array and pad it with -inf and inf
B = [-inf; sort(A(:)); inf];
% find indexes where the streak of each number begins
C = find(diff(B));
% count the length of the streaks
D = diff(C);
% extract the numbers with the longest streak
MostDuplValue = B(C(logical([0; D==max(D)])));
% calc percentage of most occuring value
MostDuplPerc = max(D)/numel(A);
```

Comment: This approach is similar to what Matlab's `mode` does